# Syntax highlighting not working on a post

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, markdown, code, syntax-highlighting

I went to [Multipart nodes with multipart subparts — style issue](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/128545/multipart-nodes-with-multipart-subparts-spacing-issue) and the questions syntax never colorized (if that is even a term to use).  I then went to another post and the syntax there was fine.  I went back to the post and waited 5 mins but it stayed grayish.

I am not sure if it is just me or others are experiencing this too with this post.

Comment: Related [How do I mark code blocks?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192/15717)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not a bug: a feature :-) The code was marked up not using Markdown (4 space indent) but using `<pre>` tags. That turns off the automatic syntax highlighting: I've edited and all should be fine now.

Comment: So, actually it was marked up as `code` before, what is more known set with backticks …

Comment: @Speravir Huh? Don't follow at all

Comment: What I meant: With `<pre>…</pre>` it is marked up as a whole code block with grey background, something what is more prominent to be done with including in backticks.